# Select Query based on values in result set

Tags: mysql, database

Is there anyway to select all from 1 table based on the result of one query which contains multiple values without having to do 2 separate queries?

Say long join query will produce a list of `id`'s

`SELECT xyz FROM table long join query WHERE id = array of ids found in result table`

added example:

```
SELECT * FROM tweets as t 
where t.user_id
in(
SELECT uff.id, uff.username 
FROM users as uf
LEFT JOIN followlinks as fl
ON uf.id = fl.user_id
LEFT JOIN users as uff
ON fl.follow_id = uff.id
WHERE uff.id = 1
)
```

The bit in the parenthesis returns an id and user name of who the user is following (uff.id=1)

How do i then get all 'tweets' by all the id's in the generated resultset

Comment: incomplete information to get an answer. Please provide some sample data and output

Comment: @raheel shan Added more

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like

edited after the OP edit

```
SELECT * FROM tweets as t 
WHERE t.user_id
in(
    SELECT uff.id   //remove the second field, you just need the id
    FROM users as uf
    LEFT JOIN followlinks as fl
    ON uf.id = fl.user_id
    LEFT JOIN users as uff
    ON fl.follow_id = uff.id
    WHERE uff.id = 1
)
```

Comment: What is long and Query? Are they separate tables?

Comment: It was in the question. I think it's just a short way to say: "I have a long set of joins here before my where conditions".

Comment: Cant quite get the results I'm expecting, does my update make my issue clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `table2`.id FROM `table2` )
```

You might want to check documentation for [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT xyz FROM table_A join table_B WHERE table_A.id IN (SELECT ID FROM table_C);
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying the in clause I coudnt get the results I was after but after rethinking what I was trying to do I got my results with an additional join clause

```
SELECT uff.username, t.content
FROM users as uf
JOIN followlinks as fl
ON uf.id = fl.user_id
JOIN users as uff
ON fl.follow_id = uff.id
JOIN tweets as t
ON t.user_id = uff.id
WHERE uf.id = 1
```